# how can I match all the key value pair in python which running too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, recommendation-engine

*User-item affinity and recommendations :*
I am creating a table which suggests "customers who bought this item also bought algorithm "
Input dataset

```
productId   userId
Prod1        a
Prod1        b
Prod1        c
Prod1        d
prod2        b
prod2        c
prod2        a
prod2        b
prod3        c
prod3        a
prod3        d
prod3        c
prod4        a
prod4        b
prod4        d
prod4        a
prod5        d
prod5        a
```

Output required

```
Product1    Product2    score
Prod1       prod3
Prod1       prod4
Prod1       prod5
prod2       Prod1
prod2       prod3
prod2       prod4
prod2       prod5
prod3       Prod1
prod3       prod2
```

```
Using code : 
#Get list of unique items
itemList=list(set(main["productId"].tolist()))

#Get count of users
userCount=len(set(main["productId"].tolist()))

#Create an empty data frame to store item affinity scores for items.
itemAffinity= pd.DataFrame(columns=('item1', 'item2', 'score'))
rowCount=0

#For each item in the list, compare with other items.
for ind1 in range(len(itemList)):

    #Get list of users who bought this item 1.
    item1Users = main[main.productId==itemList[ind1]]["userId"].tolist()
    #print("Item 1 ", item1Users)

    #Get item 2 - items that are not item 1 or those that are not analyzed already.
    for ind2 in range(ind1, len(itemList)):

        if ( ind1 == ind2):
            continue

        #Get list of users who bought item 2
        item2Users=main[main.productId==itemList[ind2]]["userId"].tolist()
        #print("Item 2",item2Users)

        #Find score. Find the common list of users and divide it by the total users.
        commonUsers= len(set(item1Users).intersection(set(item2Users)))
        score=commonUsers / userCount

        #Add a score for item 1, item 2
        itemAffinity.loc[rowCount] = [itemList[ind1],itemList[ind2],score]
        rowCount +=1
        #Add a score for item2, item 1. The same score would apply irrespective of the sequence.
        itemAffinity.loc[rowCount] = [itemList[ind2],itemList[ind1],score]
        rowCount +=1

#Check final result
itemAffinity
```

**the code is running perfectly fine on a sample dataset but

The code is taking too long to run in dataset containing 100,000 rows. Please help me optimize the code.**

Comment: I guess `userCount=len(set(main["productId"].tolist()))` should be `userCount=len(set(main["userId"].tolist()))`

Comment: Second method provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to create a cartesian product of productId. See code below,

## Method 1(works with smaller dataset)

```
result=(main.drop_duplicates(['productId','userId'])
            .assign(cartesian_key=1)
            .pipe(lambda x:x.merge(x,on='cartesian_key'))
            .drop('cartesian_key',axis=1)
            .loc[lambda x:(x.productId_x!=x.productId_y) & (x.userId_x==x.userId_y)]
            .groupby(['productId_x','productId_y']).size()
            .div(data['userId'].nunique()))

result

Prod1   prod2   0.75
Prod1   prod3   0.75
Prod1   prod4   0.75
Prod1   prod5   0.5
prod2   Prod1   0.75
prod2   prod3   0.5
prod2   prod4   0.5
prod2   prod5   0.25
prod3   Prod1   0.75
prod3   prod2   0.5
prod3   prod4   0.5
prod3   prod5   0.5
prod4   Prod1   0.75
prod4   prod2   0.5
prod4   prod3   0.5
prod4   prod5   0.5
prod5   Prod1   0.5
prod5   prod2   0.25
prod5   prod3   0.5
prod5   prod4   0.5
```

## Method 2

```
result = (df.groupby(['productId','userId']).size()
            .clip(upper=1)
            .unstack()
            .assign(key=1)
            .reset_index()
            .pipe(lambda x:x.merge(x,on='key'))
            .drop('key',axis=1)
            .loc[lambda x:(x.productId_x!=x.productId_y)]
            .set_index(['productId_x','productId_y'])
            .pipe(lambda x:x.set_axis(x.columns.str.split('_',expand=True),axis=1,inplace=False))
            .swaplevel(axis=1)
            .pipe(lambda x:(x['x']+x['y']))
            .fillna(0)
            .div(2) 
            .mean(axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark. Really appreciate it. getting a perfect output for a sample dataset. but still getting memory error for the main data comprising of 2 columns and 40k rows. Any advice would be highly valuable

Comment: @pranjaljain99 It is expected as 40k*40k rows is no joke! I'll have a look later to see if it's possible to arrange into matrix format.

Comment: Can you please explain me the part in method 1 where you calculated the score. Actually, I need a score something like ```        commonUsers= len(set(item1Users).intersection(set(item2Users)))
        score=commonUsers / userCount```

Comment: @pranjaljain99 Last two steps. groupby size divided by number of users. Please codes line by line to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Yes, algorithm could be improved. You are recalculating user list for items in inside loop multiple times. **You can just get a dictionary of item and their users outside loops.**

```
# get unique items
items = set(main.productId)

n_users = len(set(main.userId))

# make a dictionary of item and users who bought that item
item_users = main.groupby('productId')['userId'].apply(set).to_dict()

# iterate over combinations of item1 and item2 and store scores
result = []
for item1, item2 in itertools.combinations(items, 2):

  score = len(item_users[item1] & item_users[item2]) / n_users
  item_tuples = [(item1, item2), (item2, item1)]
  result.append((item1, item2, score))
  result.append((item2, item1, score)) # store score for reverse order as well

# convert results to a dataframe
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["item1", "item2", "score"])
```

Timing differences:

Original implementation from question

`# 3 loops, best of 3: 41.8 ms per loop`

Mark's Method 2

`# 3 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop`

Implementation in this answer

`# 3 loops, best of 3: 3.01 ms per loop`

Comment: I don't think that the score is correct. I tried your solution, with the data set in this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373669/alternative-to-make-a-nested-for-loop-faster-product-recommendation?noredirect=1#comment101232501_57373669). The formula should be: score = CommonUsers / userCount.  (Shaver & Babyfoon = 0.1111, Shaver & CoffeeMachine = 0.3333, Shaver & Blender = 0.2222 etc.).

Comment: you are right! i mistakenly divided by total items instead of total users. I have corrected the solution.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine on my dummy data. But on my real data, I receive this error: 


  File "<ipython-input-23-75e8f7da78af>", line 3, in <module>
    score = len(item_users[item1] & item_users[item2]) / n_users

KeyError: nan

Maybe any ideas how to fix that :-)

Comment: Some of your items seems to be nan. You should convert `productId` dtype to `str`. Add this line at top  `main['productId'] = main['productId'].astype(str)`