# How can I run Analysis grouped by Column value, instead of using the whole dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working on a Python [product recommendation system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162718/how-can-i-match-all-the-key-value-pair-in-python-which-running-too-long) (see answer Mohsin hasan).

The script simple takes two variables (UserId, ItemId) as input, and give as output the affinity score between two products.

However, I have added a third column (country). **I want to do the analysis separately, per country (not the whole data frame)**.

Originally, I used R, where the dplyr's 'group_by' function should help. But currently I am stuck (see my tries below). Anyone any idea's how I can do this analysis per country? (I have the feeling that also 'pandas.DataFrame.groupby' could solve this, instead of my attempt to use a for loop).

**Example data (please note: only difference is that I added the country column:**

```
UserId      ItemId          Country

1           Babyphone       Netherlands
1           Babyphone       Netherlands
1           CoffeeMachine   Netherlands
2           CoffeeMachine   Netherlands
2           Shaver          Netherlands
3           Shaver          Netherlands
3           CoffeeMachine   Netherlands
4           CoffeeMachine   Netherlands
4           Shaver          Netherlands
4           Blender         Netherlands
5           Blender         Netherlands
5           BabyPhone       Netherlands
5           Shaver          Netherlands
6           Shaver          Netherlands
7           CoffeeMachine   Netherlands
7           CoffeeMachine   Netherlands
8           BabyPhone       Netherlands
9           Blender         Netherlands
9           Blender         Netherlands   
1           Babyphone       Germany
1           Babyphone       Germany
1           CoffeeMachine   Germany
2           CoffeeMachine   Germany
2           Shaver          Germany
3           Shaver          Germany
3           CoffeeMachine   Germany
4           CoffeeMachine   Germany
4           Shaver          Germany
4           Blender         Germany
5           Blender         Germany
5           BabyPhone       Germany
5           Shaver          Germany
6           Shaver          Germany
7           CoffeeMachine   Germany
7           CoffeeMachine   Germany
8           BabyPhone       Germany
9           Blender         Germany
9           Blender         Germany
```

**Working -original- code (working with UserId and ItemId, without Country)**

```
# main is our data.

# get unique items
items = set(main.productId)

n_users = len(set(main.userId))

# make a dictionary of item and users who bought that item
item_users = main.groupby('productId')['userId'].apply(set).to_dict()

# iterate over combinations of item1 and item2 and store scores
result = []
for item1, item2 in itertools.combinations(items, 2):

  score = len(item_users[item1] & item_users[item2]) / n_users
  item_tuples = [(item1, item2), (item2, item1)]
  result.append((item1, item2, score))
  result.append((item2, item1, score)) # store score for reverse order as well

# convert results to a dataframe
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["item1", "item2", "score"])
```

**My Try (with country, but it is not working). What I have tried?**

1. Filter the dataframe per country (yes, this sucks because it is not dynamic)
2. Loop over the data frames (every country, has 1 data frame)
3. Try to insert the solution (see above), and apply for the data frames separately.
4. As you can see, it is unfortunately not working...

   ```
          Netherlands = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Netherlands']
          Germany     = df.loc[df['Country'] == 'Germany']
          results = []
          for dataset in (Netherlands, Germany):
              for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
              Country = row['Country'] # Need to bind the name of the df later to the results 

              items = set(dataset.ItemId) #Get unique Items per country
              n_users = len(set(dataset.UserId) # Get unique number of users per country 
              item_users = dataset.groupby('ItemId'['UserId'].apply(set).to_dict() # I tried to add country here, but without results. 

              for item1, item2 in itertools.combinations(items, 2):
                   print("item1", item1)
                   print("item2", item2)
                   score = len(item_users[item1] & item_users[item2]) / n_users
                   item_tuples = [(item1, item2), (item2, item1)]
                   result.append((item1, item2, score))
                   result.append((item2, item1, score)) # store score for reverse order as well
                   result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["item1", "item2", "score"])
   ```

**Edit1: Expected output**

[image]

**Edit 2** How is the score calculated? 
The score is representing: How many of the Customers are buying a product combination together.

For example, in the data you see that Shaver & Coffeemachine = 0.333 (because 3 persons, out of the 9 persons, bought this combination PER COUNTRY). In the first code, the score is working perfectly. But, I am not able to run it per country (that is the key issue here).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to add an expected output?

Comment: Or at least explain how a score can be calculcated. Please always give an example data and expected output and explain what you want to do in words, not with code which is way harder to understand esepcially when you use nested for loops.

Comment: Hi @Erfan, sure. I have added an output of the model. What the score is: How many of the Customers are buying a product combination together. For example, in the data you see that Shaver & Coffeemachine = 0.333 (because 3 persons, out of the 9 persons, bought this combination PER COUNTRY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go

=^..^=

As You mentioned group by will by used. First move you score loop into function with additional field 'country' and then use it on grouped data frames, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
```

Move score into function:

```
def get_score(item):
    country = item[0]
    df = item[1]

    # get unique items
    items = set(df.ItemId)
    n_users = len(set(df.UserId))

    # make a dictionary of item and users who bought that item
    item_users = df.groupby('ItemId')['UserId'].apply(set).to_dict()

    # iterate over combinations of item1 and item2 and store scores
    result = []
    for item1, item2 in itertools.combinations(items, 2):

      score = len(item_users[item1] & item_users[item2]) / n_users
      item_tuples = [(item1, item2), (item2, item1)]
      result.append((item1, item2, score, country))
      result.append((item2, item1, score, country)) # store score for reverse order as well

    # convert results to a dataframe
    result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["item1", "item2", "score", 'country'])
    return result
```

Group data by Country and then loop over each group to get score:

```
grouped_data = df.groupby(['Country'])

df_list = []
for item in list(grouped_data):
    df_list.append(get_score(item))

# concat frames
df = pd.concat(df_list)
# remove rows with 0 score
df = df[df['score'] > 0]
```

Output:

```
            item1          item2     score      country
0       BabyPhone        Blender  0.111111      Germany
1         Blender      BabyPhone  0.111111      Germany
4       BabyPhone         Shaver  0.111111      Germany
5          Shaver      BabyPhone  0.111111      Germany
8         Blender  CoffeeMachine  0.111111      Germany
9   CoffeeMachine        Blender  0.111111      Germany
10        Blender         Shaver  0.222222      Germany
11         Shaver        Blender  0.222222      Germany
14  CoffeeMachine         Shaver  0.333333      Germany
15         Shaver  CoffeeMachine  0.333333      Germany
16  CoffeeMachine      Babyphone  0.111111      Germany
17      Babyphone  CoffeeMachine  0.111111      Germany
0       BabyPhone        Blender  0.111111  Netherlands
1         Blender      BabyPhone  0.111111  Netherlands
4       BabyPhone         Shaver  0.111111  Netherlands
5          Shaver      BabyPhone  0.111111  Netherlands
8         Blender  CoffeeMachine  0.111111  Netherlands
9   CoffeeMachine        Blender  0.111111  Netherlands
10        Blender         Shaver  0.222222  Netherlands
11         Shaver        Blender  0.222222  Netherlands
14  CoffeeMachine         Shaver  0.333333  Netherlands
15         Shaver  CoffeeMachine  0.333333  Netherlands
16  CoffeeMachine      Babyphone  0.111111  Netherlands
17      Babyphone  CoffeeMachine  0.111111  Netherlands
```

Comment: It looks so simple, briljant! Thanks a lot @Zaraki Kenpachi

Comment: One question: this line (      item_tuples = [(item1, item2), (item2, item1)]
) is, I guess, not needed?